# Maintaining a WebSocket connection with React-Router

Tags: reactjs, websocket, react-router

In my React App, I establish a websocket connection in the homepage, and when a user navigates to another route, the connection stays, but if they manually open that route in their address bar, no connection is established. Do I just have to establish a connection in every route? Does React-Router keep my websocket object in scope through different routes so I could do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example on how to do this, based on the basic getting-started code of react-router. The important thing is to make sure the websocket is created and opened in the App itself, not in any particular route. This way it works no matter which way the application is opened, i.e., on any route/URL, while still maintaining the connection between routes.

Client:

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

let ws;
let buffer = [];
const sendWhenOpen = (text) => {
  if (ws.readyState == 1) {
    ws.send(text);
  } else {
    buffer.push(text);
    ws.onopen = () => {
      buffer.forEach( (x) => {
        ws.send(x);
      });
    };
  }
}

export default function App() {
  ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/');
  sendWhenOpen('connected!');

  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        {/* A <Switch> looks through its children <Route>s and
            renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/users">
            <Users />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Home() {
  sendWhenOpen('user opened home');
  return <h2>Home</h2>;
}

function About() {
  sendWhenOpen('user opened about');
  return <h2>About</h2>;
}

function Users() {
  sendWhenOpen('user opened users');
  return <h2>Users</h2>;
}
```

Server:

```js
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
  });

  ws.send('something');
});
```

Comment: Could I separate the component functions/classes into their own files and then import them? Or does using websockets with react-router mean I can't?

Comment: yes, of course you could. This was just an example. You will need to pass down the `ws` object to the components if you don't use a file-scoped variable. But that's all possible, either as a prop to the component, or by defining the `ws` in a shared global scope, e.g., `window`.